How can I get my R formula to correctly parse a true/false statement as one of its arguments?
I have a fictional weighted survey dataset that shows how responses to the question "I enjoy driving fast" vary by respondents' car colors. Here's a sample of the original dataset:
Car_Color   Weight  Enjoy_Driving_Fast
White   0.0002849   Slightly Disagree
Red     0.0010247   Slightly Disagree
Black   0.0046459   Strongly Agree
Red     0.0048461   Strongly Agree
Red     0.0060173   Strongly Agree
Black   0.0062723   Agree
Red     0.0083730   Strongly Agree
Black   0.0115573   Strongly Agree
Black   0.0131331   Strongly Agree
White   0.0156400   Strongly Agree
White   0.0201834   Slightly Agree
White   0.0209492   Strongly Disagree

And here's a copy of my code that imports this dataset, then converts it to a survey design object:
library(tidyverse)
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(fastDummies)

df_car_survey <- read_csv(
'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kburchfiel/car_survey_data/refs/heads/main/car_survey.csv') 
car_survey_des <- df_car_survey %>% as_survey_design(
  weights = 'Weight')

I am working on a post-hoc chi squared test that will determine whether the proportion of red car owners who agreed to this question differs from the corresponding proportion of white car owners. Because my data is stored within a survey design object, this test will be conducted using the survey library's svychisq() function.
I tried to run this chi squared test using the following code (which is based on Chapter 6 of Exploring Complex Survey Data Analysis Using R):
chi2_car_color_agreement_red_white_agree <- car_survey_des %>% filter(
  Car_Color %in%
c("Red", "White")) %>% drop_na(Car_Color) %>% svychisq(
  formula = ~ Car_Color + (Enjoy_Driving_Fast == "Agree"),
  design = .,
  statistic = "Chisq",
  na.rm = TRUE
)

However, I received the following error:
Error in `[.data.frame`(design$variables, , as.character(cols)) : 
  undefined columns selected

I think the issue here is with the (Enjoy_Driving_Fast == "Agree") component of the formula. Is there a way to modify that component in order to make it compatible with R's formula logic?
I was able to get around this issue by creating a dummy variable that indicates whether or not the respondent chose 'Agree' as their response to the "I enjoy driving fast" question, then passing that variable to the formula in place of (Enjoy_Driving_Fast == "Agree"). Nevertheless, I would like to find a way to get the original formula to work so that I can skip the dummy variable creation step.

How exactly did you construct car_survey_des? The svychisq doesn't seem to take a data.frame directly. Make sure to include all necessary library() calls to get your code to run and share your data in an easier format to copy/paste such as a dput to remove any importing ambiguity. Maybe try ~ Car_Color + I(Enjoy_Driving_Fast == "Agree") with the I() function for evaluating expressions.

Maybe I (Enjoy_Driving_Fast == "Agree"), The I function lets you do evaluation within formulae.

Don't you want to combine "Agree" with "Strongly Agree"? As it is, you are trying to test "Agree" vs. the other 3 categories ("Strongly Agree", "Strongly Disagree", and "Disagree"). You probably want to test "Agree" and "Strongly Agree" on the one hand vs.  "Strongly Disagree", and "Disagree" on the other.

Thanks for the prompt responses, everyone, I updated my original question to include code that imports the dataset and then converts it to a survey design object. I also tried inserting 'I' before (Enjoy_Driving_Fast == 'Agree'), but I continued to receive an 'undefined columns selected' error.
And yes, in a real-life situation, I would consolidate the responses to just two categories.

By looking at the source code of the two functions, svychisq appears to be unable to handle (Enjoy_Driving_Fast == "Agree").
Using the anes_2020 dataset as described in the book to avoid confounding issues, we can see what happens when we step through their code:
renv::install("tidy-survey-r/srvyrexploR")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(survey)
library(srvyr)
library(srvyrexploR)

data("anes_2020")
targetpop <- 231592693

anes_adjwgt <- anes_2020 %>%
  mutate(Weight = Weight / sum(Weight) * targetpop)

anes_des <- anes_adjwgt %>%
  as_survey_design(
    weights = Weight,
    strata = Stratum,
    ids = VarUnit,
    nest = TRUE
  )
# this works as expected
anes_des %>%
  svychisq(
    formula = ~ TrustGovernment + TrustPeople,
    design = .,
    statistic = "Wald",
    na.rm = TRUE
  )

We can break things in the same way:
anes_des %>%
  svychisq(
    formula = ~ TrustGovernment + (TrustPeople=="Some of the time"),
    design = .,
    statistic = "Wald",
    na.rm = TRUE
  )
Error in `[.data.frame`(design$variables, , as.character(cols)) : 
  undefined columns selected

Now onto the source code.
surveychisq.R
svychisq.survey.design<-function(formula, design,
                   statistic=c("F","Chisq","Wald","adjWald","lincom","saddlepoint","wls-score"),
                   na.rm=TRUE,...){

# yadda
cols<-formula[[2]][[3]]
# yadda
colvar<-unique(design$variables[,as.character(cols)])
# yadda

}

When formula = ~ TrustGovernment + TrustPeople:
form = as.formula(~ TrustGovernment + TrustPeople, env = anes_des)
colvar <- as.character(form[[2]][[3]])
colvar
[1] "TrustPeople"
anes_des$variables[1:5 , colvar]
# A tibble: 5 × 1
  TrustPeople        
  <fct>              
1 About half the time
2 Some of the time   
3 Some of the time   
4 Most of the time   
5 Some of the time   

surveychisq simply turns the two terms of the formula (which are the second and third elements since + is the first) into character variables and selects from design$variable using base R column subsetting, df[ , "col"]. Returning to the formula that breaks the function:
form = as.formula(~ TrustGovernment + (TrustPeople=="Some of the time"), env = anes_des)
colvar <- as.character(form[[2]][[3]])
colvar
[1] "("                                   "TrustPeople == \"Some of the time\""

We actually get a length 2 character vector, of which neither are columns in design$variables.
anes_des$variables[1:5 , colvar]
Error in `anes_des$variables[1:5, colvar]`:
! Can't subset columns that don't exist.
✖ Columns `(` and `TrustPeople == "Some of the time"` don't exist.

So why does it work in svyttest? Because the author implemented the function significantly differently. Note the use of eval(bquote( in svyttest.R
eval(bquote(# blah)

R's non-standard evaluation is complicated enough to write a book on, so details are way outside the scope of this question.
bquote
eval

Thank you for such a detailed and well-documented answer. Would it be fair to say that the svychisq source code would need to be updated in order for my sample code to run? I can simply create dummy variables in the meantime to get around this issue.

@KBurchfiel my pleasure :). And to your question, yes I think that's correct. It will be easier to just mutate a new dummy variable column. If I remember correctly, the function also requires both variables be factors. So you'll have sometime like df %>% mutate(enjoy = as.factor(Enjoy_Driving_Fast)). (Writing this comment on my phone so I can't test my suggestion. Let me know if you run into further issues.)
